# Load images in another thread with progress in QML

Tags: python, qt, qml

I use QML and PyQt. I use a model from Python, and view it's data in QML with a delegate.

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: container

    ListView {
        id: tweetListView
        anchors.fill: parent;
        clip: true
        model: mymodel
        delegate: TweetDelegate {
        //...
        }
}
```

I need to open images in QML, so I use

```
Image {
   //...
   source: url
   OnClicked: {
       busy_icon = true;
       // mainWindow is a Python object
       mainWindow.fetch_and_open(url);
       busy_icon = false;
   }
}
```

but when `fetch_and_open()` is running, the UI will freeze, so we'll never is the busy icon. I need to turn on busy icon, to fetch image in another thread, and send a signal `LoadFinished` to the delegate to turn off the busy icon.

But how do I communicate with the delegate outside the delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to Unfortunately, your code needs to become more complicated. QML runs in a single thread and any calls into python are synchronous and blocking.  The answer is have your python code first create a new thread. Then perform your fetch and open operation within that new thread.  The tricky part is now you need a way to tell your busy_icon when to finish. This is accomplished by creating a signal in your mainWindow object that can be fired when loading is finished.  Its trivial from there to hook up a signal handler to tell your busy icon to stop.